# Nhibernate query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have this domain model,

```
class UserInfo{
    int UserId{get;set;}
    string UserName{get;set;}
    IList<Task> Tasks{get;set;}
}

class Task{
    int TaskId{get;set;}
    string TaskName{get;set;}
    UserInfo AssignedTo{get;set;}
}

class UserMap: ClassMap<UserInfo>
{ 
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x=>x.UserId);
        Map(x=>x.UserName)
        HasMany(x=>x.Tasks);
    }
 }
```

Now, a user may have any number of tasks assigned to him, but Active is always none or one.
This is stored in another table and defined through another entity. So, if there is an active task for a child, there exists a record in ActiveTask table.

```
class ActiveTask{
    int Id{get;set;}
    int UserId{get;set;}
    int TaskId{get;set;}
    datetime CreatedOn{get;set;}
}
```

Questions,

- How to map ACTIVETASK with USERINFO
- I want to fetch a list of users, along with active task (if any).

Please suggest how to do it

Comment: I think you should improve your mappings, so UserInfo have collection of tasks in it.

Comment: K i did. Now in userinfo, should i have a distinct mapping for ActiveTask??

Comment: I think that Nhibernate needs properties to be `public virtual` but I'm not 100% sure, check my answer and tell if it works as needed

Comment: @wudzik There can be at most one task Active for any user. So, there is a 1to1 mapping. And yes ActiveTask is just a helper table (created because just didn't want to bloat UserInfo with other audit info like CreatedOn, CreatedBy, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be hard-pressed to find the one good answer because it will depend on other factors such as the number of tasks you expect a given user to have. That said, it sounds like you're trying to use a single collection of `Task` and simply mark one as active. From a domain perspective, I'd bet this is the reality of things. People have many tasks, one is active. An active task is still a task.

If that's the case, then one option is to add an `IsActive` property to your `Task` object, then set your fetch strategy in the mapping to be eager (otherwise you'll have a select n+1 issue). Then, your `ActiveTask` property could use linq to select the `Task` in the collection that has `Active == true`.

If you went this route, then you'd want to add logic in your class to set a task active such that all other tasks were set to inactive. Something like this:

```
class UserInfo
{
    public virtual int UserId{get;set;}
    public virtual string UserName{get;set;}
    public virtual IList<Task> Tasks{get;set;}

    public virtual Task ActiveTask
    {
        get
        {
            return Tasks.FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsActive == true);
        {
    }

    public void SetActive(Task task)
    {
        // Set all tasks to inactive
        // Set the task in question to active
    }
}
```

If it were me I would probably also change the `Tasks` collection from an autoproperty to having a backing field and use `protected internal` for setting so you could ensure that the list is only assigned during mapping.

Note that if you have a large number of users or tasks the eager fetch strategy could become costly. In this case, then you probably would want to use a separate table to track which task is active and map that way.

### Update

I went back and checked on some other projects I had done that had similar requirements, and in one case I actually changed it so the parent object held a reference to the active child object. So your `UserInfo` table in the database would have an FK column of `ActiveTask_Id` which would relate to the `Task` table's PK. Then your mapping of the user would be like (assuming you're overriding an automap):

```
public class UserInfoOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<UserInfo>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<UserInfo> mapping)
    {
        mapping.References(x => x.ActiveTask).Fetch.Join();
    }
}
```

You would then simply set a task to the `ActiveTask` property of your `UserInfo` object and save.